# How to get a download URL for files in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python, google-cloud-storage

I have created a service using :

storage.Client(project='project_name', credentials=credentials)

https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html

And I'm able to upload, delete and list the files in a users Google Cloud bucket. I've seen an option to download the file to a server, but is there any option to get a downloadable link?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the downloadable link replacing the values of the following string:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket.name}/{blob.name}
```

If you need to limit permissions or time to make the request, you can [generate a Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-python)

> A signed URL is a URL that provides limited permission and time to
>   make a request. Signed URLs contain authentication information in
>   their query string, allowing users without credentials to perform
>   specific actions on a resource. When you generate a signed URL, you
>   specify a user or service account which must have sufficient
>   permission to make the request that the signed URL will make. After
>   you generate a signed URL, anyone who possesses it can use the signed
>   URL to perform specified actions, such as reading an object, within a
>   specified period of time.

Comment: What I want is to get downloadURL for files(type-not public) in a users Google Cloud bucket using the credentials got after the user authentication. I am able to create a signed url for files in my bucket using the service account file created in the same account. Is there any option similar to AWS where we can create a signed url for files in a another persons bucket using the authentication token.

Comment: As I understand you want to get object link to download it in web browser?

Comment: yes , but not for the files in my Google Cloud Storage. For the files in a users account using the token got after user authentication

Comment: Seems this feature is not available in Google Cloud https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/index

Comment: I will recommend you create Feature Request in GCP here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: ok will do that

Comment: Any luck with this feature request?

Comment: @subin_john_ Please could you share the Feature Request about downloading the file through a link after being authenticated ?

Comment: Hi Guys! I just found the FR regarding this functionality. Please keep in mind that there is no ETA for the functionality. I suggest to star the issue in order to be notified if there is any updates:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150633508

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an access token to sign a URL because access tokens are time limited (about an hour). An alternative to using the private key file to sign a url, is to use IAM's SignBlob functionality.
You can use it with `“gsutil”`  by the command  `”gsutil signurl -u --”`  as mentioned in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl). Note that with this method, the signed url is only valid for 12 hours, as compared to the maximum of 7 days as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

> The signBlob service regularly rotates the private key that it uses.
> Signed URLs generated are usable for at least 12 hours, but may stop
> working prior to your set expiration time if the expiration time is
> greater 12 hours. Given this, signed URLs generated from signBlob are
> best used for short-lived access to resources.

Comment: @subin_john_ Posted an answer, Is it helpful?